# LimeJS Custom Sprite Swallowing events

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, google-closure-library, limejs

I made a custom Lime JS sprite class by doing:

```
test.obj = function() {
  lime.Sprite.call(this);
  .
  .
  this.label = new lime.Label(). ...;
  this.appendChild(this.label);
}
goog.inherits(test.obj, lime.Sprite);
```

I'm unable to get the label click to bubble up to the root program; it always swallows the events.  Is there something special you have to do to get a click on the label to bubble up to my root event handler, which is:

```
goog.events.listen(objinstance, ["click", "touchstart"], function() { .. });
```

Comment: What is objinstance in this case? Is it pointing to the instance of lime.Label above?

Comment: No, my custom `test.obj` class.

Comment: Are you saying you added a similar listen function on the label somewhere in that class, and its callback is the only one that fires?

Answer (score 1):

Are you stopping any propagation? It is quite strange for it to happen otherwise. Look into the listener function which should pass down a goog.events.BrowserEvent object as a parameter and see if they are automatically stopping some propagations from inside the library's source.